# C# Documentation Plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking for a Visual Studio 2012 plugin / method that will allow me to access the [.NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) section of the MSDN library without an internet connection.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start -> Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 -> Help Viewer does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to install the Help Viewer (if you haven't already got it).

In Visual Studio, under the "Help" menu, set the "Help Preference" to "Launch in Help Viewer" - it should download the relevant content for you if you haven't already got it.

Comment: Thankyou! I have never used the Help Viewer before and admittedly I feel a bit foolish for thinking that there wouldn't be an offline help tool provided. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Jon's correct answer

It's possible that during installation you chose to not cache the documentation locally and instead access it from online.  To change this post installation so you can see it in the Help Viewer do the following

- Help -> Add and Remove Help Content
- Change the Installation Source to Disk
- Hit "Update"